# How to send data to ble?

Tags: android

I have use  mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor) or writeCharacteristic(characteristic)
to send data to ble devices.

but the devices can't received.I don't konw why?

This is my code :

```
 public void writeDataToBel() {

    if ((gattCharacteristics_send.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0) {
        System.out.println("have permission");
    }
String  send_data = "d300000000060000000000000000d900";
    gattCharacteristics_send.setValue(send_data);

    gattCharacteristics_send
        .setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);

    boolean sendStatus = mBluetoothGatt
            .writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristics_send);

    System.out.println("status-->" + sendStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it:

```
 "d300000000060000000000000000d900" chageTo byte[]


public static byte[] changeToByte(String sendData) {
        byte[] myByte = new byte[16];  
        int[] myInt = new int[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < myByte.length; i++) {
            myInt[i]=Integer.valueOf(sendData.substring(i*2, (i+1)*2), 16);
        } 
         for (int i = 0; i < myByte.length; i++) {
          myByte[i] = (byte) myInt[i];
        }
       return myByte;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the characterisitic you are writing to has a write permission. you can perform the check in the following way:

```
 if((gattCharacteristics_send.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE ) > 0) {
         gattCharacteristics_send.setValue(send_data);
         boolean sendStatus = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristics_send);
 }
```